# Does ical.net have a way to get a rrule occurrence by the index?

Tags: icalendar, rrule, ical-dotnet, ical.net

For a given `Calendar` object that has a `RecurrenceRules` set, is there a way to get occurrence 5? There is `GetOccurrences()` that will return a list of occurrences for a date range. But I can't find a way to say I want the 5th occurrence.